# Mismatched Bundle ID (Sandbox) in OneSignal

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, certificate, onesignal

I'm trying to send PN to my iOS App.

I followed the standard steps, i.e.:

- create new app and upload the development and distribution(sandbox) certificates
- put the App id in my project: OneSignal.initWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions, appId:"myAppID")
- create new template
- send a message

When I sent the PN I got "send message successfully" green message, but after a while I got a warning when I clicked on it I directed to App Settings page and the warning is:

[image: Mismatched Bundle ID (Sandbox)]

and I didn't receive any PN!!

I checked my bundle ID in my project and it's 100% matched to the uploaded certificates.

Anyone faced like this problem when trying to use OneSignal for PN?

Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

This problem happens when your application is built with a Provisioning Profile for a Bundle ID that does not match the Bundle ID of the push certificate you uploaded to OneSignal.

It is possible that you have created several builds of your application, some with the correct bundle id and some with an incorrect one. As a result you may have subscribed devices in OneSignal that are linked to different bundle ids.

If you are able to receive notifications with the latest build of your application then you can probably ignore this error. If all of the iOS notifications you send show up as "Invalid", then you must either upload a new push certificate with the correct bundle id, or build your app with a provisioning profile that matches your push certificate's bundle id.

Answer (score 0):

I got this warning on a few of my failed messages that I triggered from Zapier. I verified my Bundle ID and they are exactly the same, and I was getting other notifications just fine. As @gdeglin said I'm going to ignore this warning for now, as it doesn't seem to point an issue at this point of time. If you find any other answer to this please share, I'm sure others are facing similar issues as well.